# Proving that limit of a sequence is 0 from definitions.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, real-numbers

I had this question in a test:

Use the definition of limit in order to prove that if $\{a_n\}$ (n goes from 1 to infinity) is a sequence of real numbers such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n^2 =0$ then we must also have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n =0$.

This was my solution, which got 0/4.

Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n^2 =0$ we have that there exists a number $N\in Z^+$ such that given $\epsilon>0$ we have $|a_n^2-0| = |a_n^2| < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. But since $a_n^2 >0, |a_n^2| = a_n^2$ and hence $a_n^2<\epsilon$ for $n \geq N$. Hence, taking positive square roots on both sides and using that $\sqrt{x^2}  = |x|$ we see that $|a_n| < \epsilon _1$ when $n \geq N$ where $\epsilon_1 = \sqrt{\epsilon}$ is an arbitrary positive real number. Hence the result follows.

I personally do not feel as though I deserve 0/4 for this solution, but maybe I am missing something? The comment the tutor gave on my question paper was in the first line saying that the definition is wrong.

Comment: Yours is an almost correct argument. It remains to show that $\epsilon_1$ is actually an arbitrary positive real number (but, I mean, this is obvious!). Personally I would have given you 4/4.

Comment: the solution they used uses that if $\epsilon^2$ is real then $\epsilon$ is real, but they didn't have prove that.

Comment: Thanks Crostul! Do you think I should take it to my lecturer for a remark?

Comment: I agree that looks good. The issue your teacher may have had is that you usually want to go back and re-write the proof so that it is of the form "for any $\epsilon>0$, we can find $N$ such that... . In other words, you want to START with "for any epsilon", rather than derive epsilon as you did (sort of). But it would not be difficult to rewrite

Comment: @ElliotG what do you mean?

Comment: What you wrote is the following. For every $\epsilon>0$, there is $N$ such that $|a_n|<\sqrt{\epsilon}$ for all $n\geq N$. Although this is equivalent to saying that $a_n\rightarrow 0$, but you tutor may think this is not the $\epsilon-N$ DEFINITION.

Comment: How are these not equivalent if both are arbitrary real numbers through?

Comment: So what you wrote is "you can find an epsilon with this property, and you can make it arbitrarily small", but technically that "you can make epsilon arbitrarily small" needs proof itself. We usually want the form "let epsilon be an arbitrarily small number, and show that it has this property". It may not seem like a big issue, but it's possible your instructor does if he/she wants to stress proper proof writing.

Comment: Sometimes I think these "obvious" proofs are the hard ones because since we all know they are true we are prone to make logical jumps

Comment: Actually, the formulation "there exists a number N∈Z+ such that given ϵ>0 we have ... for all n≥N" is incorrect (and as such it might justly provoke the wrath of your tutor). The correct phrasing is "for every ϵ>0, there exists a number N∈Z+ such that we have ... for all n≥N".

Comment: To expand on Did's comment. The way you phrased it means that you have one $N$ that works for any $\varepsilon$, when in truth the choice of $N$ depends on $\varepsilon$. This is why you were marked down, but I agree that it was harsh to mark you completely wrong instead of giving you partial credit. You should definitely ask your tutor why you got no points at all.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's clearer just to note that:

if $\epsilon >0$ then there is an $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $n>N\Rightarrow \vert a_n\vert^2 <\epsilon ^2$. Then $\vert a_n\vert \leq \epsilon  $.